# Explorer Contextmenu program possible to start only once for multiple marked files?

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I've added a program to the Windows Explorer context menu which shall process all files that are given to it via Explorer. Thus I mark files and then right click and click on "myProcessFiles".

It functions nicely with one exception when I mark multiple files the application starts once per file instead of once with all files given as Parameters (as I had expected).

I've added a key for MyProcessFiles to */Shell within the registry.

Then in MyProcessFiles I added the following command key:

```
"C:\MyProcessFiles.exe" "%1"
```

My question here is: Is there any way to make it so that the program is started only once?

*Note: As the program itself that is being started (MyProcessFiles) is a C# program I also added C# to tags as it could be that a possible solution 
is programming language based (aka only via the program itself).*

Answer (score 0):

By searching with different key words than I used before I stumbled upon an old question (1 year old) from another site where the same Problem was in existence.

In essence 2 ways were discussed there as possible Solutions

1. Writing a Shell Extension with a link to the tutorial: [The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/830/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens) (part 2 holds the exact info for a program operating on multiple files at once)
2. Instead of adding the program into the "normal" context menu to put it into the "send to" context menu. This can be done by dropping a link to the application into the %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo folder (note that that was from a Windows 7 answer on the other site so it could be different for other Versions of the operating system).